# Salvar item em Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

Possuo um combobox com alguns items adicionados via formulário, pela propriedade Items (Collection).

Gostaria de poder deixar a cargo do usuário, a digitação de novos textos nesse combobox, que no meu caso, é um combobox de categorias de produtos.

Criei um código que adiciona o texto digitado ao combobox, mas ele não permanece lá quando o formulário é reiniciado, minha pergunta é, tem como adicionar um item e fazê-lo permanecer nos itens?

Obs: Não há a possibilidade de eu usar banco de dados para isso.

Meu código:

```
private void btnIncluirItens_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // para inserir na última posição

    int cnt = cbCategoriaProduto.Items.Count;
    if (cbCategoriaProduto.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        cbCategoriaProduto.Items.Insert(cnt, cbCategoriaProduto.Text);

    }
    else
    {
        cbCategoriaProduto.Items.Insert(cnt, "Item " + cnt);
    }
    cbCategoriaProduto.Text = ""; //limpa a caixa de texto após a inclusão

}
```

Comment: Você quer salvar permanentemente os inseridos, ou só na sessão ou só durante o acesso a página?

Comment: Vc quer manter os itens na `combobox` somente quando seu formulário de adição de itens é encerrado ou quer que os itens permaneçam quando toda a aplicação é encerrada?

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se este código é o suficiente para o que pretendes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace drawing {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            comboBox1.Location = new Point(20, 60);
            comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            comboBox1.Size = new Size(245, 25);

            comboBox1.Items.Add("A");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("B");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("C");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("D");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Add");

            this.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
            comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += OnComboBox1SelectionChanged;
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }

        private void OnComboBox1SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox temp = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (temp.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Add")
            {
                temp.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }
    }
}
```